# Control placed in runat=server table sets SQL parameter at NULL on Update

Tags: asp.net, null, sql-update, formview, runatserver

I have a page with FormView and a plain html table inside. The table serves for layout and contains child controls data-bind to SqlDataSource. My problem is that if I add runat=server attribute to the table declaration, all controls inside the table set my SQL parameters at NULL in DataSource_Updating event and thus the record gets updated with NULLs instead of actual values. If I don't add runat=server, everything works fine. Sample of my code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="SettingsFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SettingsDataSource"
        DefaultMode="Edit" Width="560px">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <strong>Settings</strong>
            <table runat="server" width="350px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="160">
                        Time (sec)
                        <dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="textTime" runat="server"
                            Height="21px" Number="0" Value='<%# Bind("Time") %>' Width="104px" />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        &nbsp;
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

I want to be able to remove (set invisible) some rows in code behind, that's why I need to set runat=server. However I can't get anywhere with this because SQL record updates with NULLs. Please, advice what might be wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
<!-- toggle through OnLoad (can use ID as well) -->
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" OnLoad="MakeVisibleOrNot">
<tr>
   ...
</tr>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and in the code behind:

```
protected void MakeVisibleOrNot(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ((Control) sender).Visible = ConfigUtil.DisplaySummaryComment;
}
```